# Ace editor. Set current edits state as base

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ace-editor, react-ace

I'm using [ace editor](https://ace.c9.io/) wrapped by [react-ace](https://github.com/securingsincity/react-ace) for my project.

How can I destroy all undo/redo history in certain moment when I need it?

I've tried `this.aceRef.editor.destroy();` (just react ref bound with editor), but unfortunately it doesn't play well in some circumstances.
So, I just need to clean undo/redo session/history or something like that.

Any solution?

Comment: What does "it doesn't play well in some circumstances." mean?

Comment: It destroys editor, but I need to keep it. I just need to reset edits history.

Comment: Can you do `this.aceRef.editor.value = ''`?

Comment: All modifications of value will be stored in edits history. I need to reset history.

Comment: Have you tried: `editor.getSession().setUndoManager(new ace.UndoManager())`?

Comment: yep, changes still tracked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ace editor actually has this `reset` method with `UndoManager`.

Then you need to assign temporary stored undomanager as base.

It could be done smth like that:

```
const { editor } = this.aceRef;
const session = editor.getSession();
const undoManager = session.getUndoManager();
undoManager.reset();
session.setUndoManager(undoManager);
```